# How can I keep headers and source files separated in a C++ project in NetBeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans

For my C++ project, I want to keep my headers and sources separated (i.e. not in the same folder). To do this, I have to explicitly change the directory of the source/header file by filling in the two inputs in the dialog, every single time I make a class:

[image: dialog]

Is there a way to configurate the project so that NetBeans "understands" that the headers should by default go in the "include" folder (or sources go in the "src" folder, either of the two)?

Comment: If you're looking to separate your header and source files, perhaps add a "h-" to each header and "s-" to each source file and then Netbeans should display them in two groups based upon alphabetical order

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But where do I add "h-" and "s-" exactly?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if Netbeans does organize files in alphabetical order, hence the "should" in my original comment. However, you'd still be able to specify between headers and source quickly